Query formula not grouping properly
I have a google sheet where one tab is the data entry sheet named "
Master Sheet". and I have another tab labeled "Charts/Tables". On the second tab I have a query pulling data form the first.
The query looks like this:

=QUERY('Master Sheet'!A1:N, "select B, H, I, max(K), L, M where B is
not null group by B, H, I, K, L, M order by B label B 'Transfer #', H
'Box #', I 'Total Boxes In Transfer',  M 'Shelved'")

It works, but not exactly how I need it to. I would like to also group column H but when there are entries for the same box each entry has a line in the query results.
Here is the link to my example:link
I've tried rearrnging the grouping, changing the column refernce to Col# instead of using the column letters an I am at a loss.

Can you manually add and showcase your ideal expected output somewhere in the test sheet alongside with some explanation points on why it is supposed to be that way and all...

@rockinfreakshow- I have added my ideal output with an explanation. Hope it helps.

https://i.sstatic.net/neX4sPN8.png Any reason to not consider the highlighted part for grouping?

@rockinfreakshow No reason at all. I just missed that one as an example. On the 'Master Sheet' there will be multiple entries for the same box #. That's why I would like them to be grouped.

@rockinfreakshow That looks like it does the job. Now that I see what you did, I want to apologize. That was a simple solution to my issue but for the life of me, I couldn't come up with it myself. Another set of eyes is always better. Thanks fo the help!


You may try:
=QUERY('Master Sheet'!A1:N, "select B, H, I, max(K), max(L), max(M) where B is not null group by B, H, I")


